# visual c# 2010 cant use copied code in dll

Tags: c#, dll, copy

When I copy a code from project to a dll project I cant use that code in any projects that are using this dll , although I can use any code I write in the dll project I cant use one that I pasted it in .

Maybe I have done the copying in a wrong way ? here is how I done it :

1. I copy the code from a class in a project.
2. I past it in the dll project in another class ( same name ).
3. I open a project that is using the dll and I write everything I need like the " using " statement and still , I cant use that code.

the problem is not in a specific code because I tried that with more than one code , and I have tried just rewriting everything and it worked , am I doing something wrong ?

please tell me how can I copy a code from a project to a dll project .

Comment: Most probably, you now have two classes that have the same name and same namespace

Comment: @ken2k Post your comment as answer - I bet this is exactly it.

Mohamed Atef: If you already have DLL that you can include in project, why copy-paste code and not use the DLL itself (and avoid code duplication?)

Comment: Try close and reopen visual studio

Comment: @ken2k what do you mean ? anyway I copy the code inside the class and create the class in the other project and past the code , I dont copy the namespace or the class name , and I have tried making different names.

Comment: @LB2 I have done something in a project and I want to put that in a dll , whenever I copy it in the dll in doesnt work.

Comment: @MohamedAtef "It doesn't work" isn't enough to go on - do you get exceptions?  Build errors? Are the classes public?  Are you referencing the DLL and the Namespace?

Comment: @DStanley thanks it looks like that I forgot to make them public , although sometimes it warned me to do so , thanks very much .

Comment: @MohamedAtef classes are `internal` by default, which is why they worked in the original project but not when you moved them to a separate assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that the answer is to make the class public , thanks to D stanley .